# How to convert Three.js to .stl files for 3D printing?

Tags: javascript, three.js, 3d

I found one page link: [Convert Three.js to .stl for 3D printing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32031003/convert-three-js-to-stl-for-3d-printing)

```
var exporter = new THREE.STLExporter();
var str = exporter.parse(scene);
console.log(str);
```

But when I'm using them, not export a stl file.

How can I do then?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `STLExporter.parse()` will export the specified object to a string. If you wish to save the string as a file you have to perform some more operations. As a simple approach you can use `FileSaver.js` for saving the string to a file.

First of all you have to download and include `FileSaver.js` in your code.

[Download link:](https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/)

After exporting the scene using STLExporter, convert the resulting string to a [Blob](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob) and then save the Blob as a file using FileSaver.js,

```
var exporter = new THREE.STLExporter();
var str = exporter.parse( scene ); // Export the scene
var blob = new Blob( [str], { type : 'text/plain' } ); // Generate Blob from the string
saveAs( blob, 'file.stl' ); //Save the Blob to file.stl
```

If you are not familiar with FileSaver.js you can try the following method,

```
var exporter = new THREE.STLExporter();
var str = exporter.parse( scene ); // Export the scene
var blob = new Blob( [str], { type : 'text/plain' } ); // Generate Blob from the string
//saveAs( blob, 'file.stl' ); //Save the Blob to file.stl

//Following code will help you to save the file without FileSaver.js
var link = document.createElement('a');
link.style.display = 'none';
document.body.appendChild(link);
link.href = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
link.download = 'Scene.stl';
link.click();
```

Comment: I try your suggestion  and succeed,Thank you very much!
Then,here I have so many meshes,How can I merge them and export to a stl files?thanks again!

Comment: @panda , If you export the scene, it will include all the meshes added to the scene

Comment: emm.,but I found only include last mesh,others not include.maybe it's my wrong,I will check again,Thank you very much

Comment: HariV，I know why.All meshes postion is default by world coordinate system,can not save their postion,translate and so on.How solve it?

Comment: I can't understand what you are trying to say, but in my case after loading an exported scene , I got all the meshes in the right place.

Comment: HariV,through my hard work,I solved this problem,thank you again!!!Yeah!!!

Comment: the export works fine... but each side of ab object is divided into triangles, even if the side is planar; this leades to non-printable models, which must be cleaned up with skecthfabb; how can redundant edges  be removed?

Comment: Hi, I am creating stl file using threejs stlexporter but 3d printer is not generate print of this stl file. Please let me know what I am missing.